# Trying to get rid of comma at end of a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone tell me the exact syntax to get rid of a comma at the end of a column?

```
UPDATE [Database].[schema].[Table]
SET    [Columnx] = rtrim([Columnx], ", ")
```

This does not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use substring.

Here is an example:

```
declare @test varchar(5)
select @test = '12,'

select substring(@test, 1, len(@test)-1)
```

---

In your case it would be:

```
UPDATE [Database].[schema].[Table]
SET    substring([Columnx], 1, len([Columnx])-1)
WHERE  [Columnx] like '%,'
AND  len([Columnx]) > 0
```

Comment: And this will get rid anything not just a comma (as OP wants)

Comment: Just need the comma taken away . Running this gives me an error . sg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @JamesKhan try it now. that might happen when the string was empty so I added the `len([Columnx]) > 0` condition

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE 
   [Database].[schema].[Table]
SET
    Columnx = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RTRIM(Columnx)), 2, 8000))
WHERE 
   [Columnx] like '%,'
```

Comment: is it faster to use `reverse` or is it better because `len` can have problems?

Comment: @gbn May be you should use TRIM, if the column type is varchar?

Comment: @aF.: It doesn't matter with a leading wildcard LIKE to find trailing commas = full scan of the data (eg all rows are examined). The actual method of removing the comma is **utterly irrelevant**: the difference won't be measurable.